# Kali linux purple 2024 letest version data recovery

Tags: linux, kali-linux, data-recovery

Installing new versions of kali linux purpule then i was installing a kali linux partition its "choosing partition option by default set
Guided disk partition option"

*Here i mistakenly select this one
Before I install linux my pc run with windows 11 os after installing linux my windows partition are not showing or formatting so i need help,

To recovery of my erased data recovery  how to get back
It's data

Comment: Ask at https://superuser.com/ or https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Your question is about data restoration, not Linux/UNIX per se.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov we have similar questions (and answers) here too